# Combine both on text change and debounce in rxjava for edittext

Tags: android, search, rx-java2, debouncing, android-textwatcher

I've been using `rxjava2` for a while but mostly kind of a boilerplate, I didn't clearly know its features.

I supposed to create a search `Edittext` which call method after sometime. I got it working by the following code:

```
RxTextView.textChanges(edittextSearch)
                .filter(charSequence -> charSequence.length() > 3)
                .debounce(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(string -> {
                    search(string.toString());
                }, error -> {
                    Log.e("ERROR","ERROR LISTENING: " + error.getMessage());
                });
```

However, I need one more feature for this `EditText`, which is as soon as I type, even with just one character, I would display an "X" icon to clear the input, or hide it if user manually delete all text.

I don't know if the `textChanges` method above could do that or I have to add another text watcher for the `edittextSearch`

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using a [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.html) and adding app:endIconMode="clear_text". It's part of the material design library, there are plenty of guides on how to use them.

This will automatically add a clear icon when the user begins typing, clicking the icon will clear the text and update your textChanges observable.

Comment: This could be a solution. Sorry forgot to mention that I'm using a custom view that extends `EditText` to custom something. I'll try to see if it doesn't take much effort for changing to `TextInputLayout`. Thank you for your answer

Comment: TextInputLayout wraps an EditText so you should be alright putting your custom view inside a TextInputLayout